# coordinates of 3rd point (vertex) of a right triangle knowing lengths and direction

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems, 3d, solid-angle

In a last post I wanted to know [the 3rd point of vertex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113559/z-coordinates-of-3rd-point-vertex-of-a-right-triangle-given-all-data-in-3d), actually I have some similar problem ....

I think I have all data.. for example...:

1. 3 vertex cordinates in order to have the direction(gray arrow):

   ```
    v1 = (-0.117, 1.06,0.53)   v2 = (0.82, 2.06, 0.76)  v3 = (-0.63, 2.06, 0.76)
   ```
2. distance between vertices:

   ```
   d1 =  1.125    d2 = 1.43   d3 = 1.46
   ```
3. distance between  v3 and new vertice:

   ```
    d4 = 0.8
   ```

[image: image example]

actually I know that this problem have two possible solutions

also I tried with the last equation and with [some 2d equation](http://www.ehowenespanol.com/calcular-tercer-vertice-teniendo-coordenadas-triangulo-como_179044/), also I search in all thread of math stackenchage without any good result.

thanks for any help.

Diego

thanks to @Moti for help

Comment: You are not stating clearly your problem. What are the distances? Between points? Which specific points? You need to mark the points so you can clearly state the distances. I checked one distance - and it was not correct (1.038 where it seems like 1.125...). How did you derive the gray direction?

Comment: @Moti thanks for answere... I edit the picture to clarify the vertices...  All distances are correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to solve. You use d3 twice. Do you tey to calculate a distance?

The following diagram might help you define better your need:

[image]

CE is perpendicular to CB and in the same plane.

Comment: thanks for image... which software do you use??.. anyway   I want to know the E coordinates... do you have some ideas please?

Comment: I am using GeoGebra. Finally you tell:) May be you could edit the question to reflect on what you are seeking. Here is the process you need to take:1. Find the equation of the line through EC in the plan created by ABC. 2. Solve for a point with distance 0.8 from C. 3. From the solutions you get select the one that has the opposite sign of A when you plug in the line equation of BC